# If $(y_{n})$ is bounded sequence of real numbers that doesn't converge to zero and $\lim(x_{n}-y_{n})=0$, then $\lim\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove If $(y_{n})$ is bounded sequence of real numbers that doesn't converge to zero and $\lim(x_{n}-y_{n})=0$, then $\lim\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}=1$.

My try to prove it:

$\lim(x_{n}-y_{n})=0$ means $\forall\epsilon >0, \exists n_{0}:\forall n \geq n_{0}: |x_{n}-y_{n}| < \epsilon$.

My intention is to show:  $|\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}-1| < \epsilon$, but I am not capable of showing it.

And why is there the condition that $(y_{n})$ doesn't converge to  zero ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is false. You can come up with a counterexample by splitting $\mathbb{N}$ up into even $n$ and odd $n.$

Comment: You probably need $0 < \inf y_n \leq \sup y_n < \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example:

$y_n=
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{n^2}&\text{if n even}\,\\
      1&\text{if } n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$

$x_n=
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{n}&\text{if n even}\,\\
      1&\text{if } n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$

Comment: But why does my question require the sequence $y_{n}$ not to converge to zero?

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

A way to make the statement hold is to change:

"doesn't converge to zero "

To:

" Has no subsequence that converges to zero " .

Indeed, under this stronger assumption, for $N_{1}$ sufficiently large you have that for some $\epsilon_{1} > 0 $:

$|y_{n}| \geq \varepsilon_{1} , \forall n \geq N_{1} $

Let $\varepsilon >0 $ , take $N_{2}$ large enough such that:

$$ |x_{n}-y_{n}| < \varepsilon_{1} \varepsilon , \forall n \geq N_{2}$$

Then for $n \geq \max{N_{1},N_{2}}$ you have that:

$$ |\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}} - 1 | = \frac{|x_{n}-y_{n}|}{|y_{n}|} < \frac{\varepsilon_{1} \varepsilon}{ \varepsilon_1} = \varepsilon$$